# How to get out of Python in Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, command-prompt

I'm brand new to using the command prompt, and I've just executed my first line of code from the command prompt as follows:

```
C:\Users\Michael>python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello world")
hello world
```

How do I now "get out" of Python so that I can run other commands, such as `cd`, `cp`, `ls`, etc.? I know I can just close and open a new command prompt window, but is there a command for this instead?

Comment: haha, this is really funny. you can use the `exit()` function.

Comment: ```exit()``` function or ```Ctrl+Z```

Comment: I was surprised to find that there's a duplicate for this; but whatever tutorial got you this far, surely also explains the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply running `exit()` will close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Sir, You can type `exit()` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and click on Enter.